# Show item name instead of id

Tags: sql, join

I have a table called `champions` with columns `champion_name`, `champion_item1` through `champion_item16`. The `champion_itemX` columns are integer references to `items.item_number`.

I have another table called `items` with columns `item_number`, `item_name` and `item_property`.

I would like to get a result where it will list:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
champion_name | champion_item1 | champion_item... | champion_item16 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
 Legolas      | belt           | ...              | hat             |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

or, better yet, list all items from champion Legolas:

```
-----------------------------------------------------
champion_item1  |    belt      |It holds your pants |
-----------------------------------------------------
champion_item...|    ...       |         ...        |
-----------------------------------------------------
champion_item16 |    hat       | It holds your wig  |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Storing many columns of the same relationship is bad practice. You should instead implement a *many-to-many* relationship via a [junction table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table)

Comment: It's doable (I'll let others answer how), but if you have the ability to restructure your tables, you'd probably be better served by normalizing your champion to item relationship with a [edit:not "join"] junction (thx @Phil) table.

Comment: @Palpatim I always called them *associative entities* but that wiki article makes it crystal clear :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer for this matter was given by bitsmed here:

http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=190694